# How to obtain data using Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider

Tags: encoding, ado.net, character-encoding, firebird, dataprovider

I have a question regarding obtain data using Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider. I can get data from DB w/o any problems but it seems that I use wrong char-set or encoding and I receive next: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/2554/20110717-qllq-27kb.jpg (the value of fields from DB are located in red squares).

Does anybody have any ideas how I can get data in correct way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still relevant... any ideas? =(

Comment: Hi, seems unicode related. What are the encoding and char-set you are using both in database and in connection? And what is this application you are using to show the data?

Comment: Hi! I'm using simple console application to receive data from FireBird DB (*.FDB file).

Provider I use is [Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/).

I can set Charset only to NONE, ASCII or UTF8 in other cases I receive an error: _Invalid character set specified_.

I try to get data using FbDataReader but instead of normal strings I receive something like _RC%pppb_ & etc.

Comment: AFAIR, you should not use NONE. One question, are you using this?
http://swinbrain.ict.swin.edu.au/wiki/ADO.NET,_Getting_Started_Sample
If not, take a look please.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I do in the same way and it doesn't work for me =( I tried to use all kind of allowed charsets: NONE, ASCII and UTF8; all of them have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant, but maybe it will help someone else.

Try to set charset in web.config/app.config like this:

```
 <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; 
  User=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey; Database=db.gdb; Charset=win1250;"
  providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
```

The values of the charset could also be win1250, iso859_1, iso859_2 etc. as stated [here](http://web.firebirdsql.org/firebirdtutorial/connection-string-parameters.html) or [here](http://web.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/documentation/api/1.7/FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird.FbConnectionStringBuilder.Charset.html).